# Yet another setInterval & this not working

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with `this` and `setInterval` in JavaScript. I read a couple of solutions here on SO but couldn't make them work for me. Here is my code:

```
var timer_func = function(){
    var that = this;
    var inspect = function(clusters){

        var clength = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < that.clusters.length; i++){   //---> undefined that.clusters.length
            clength += that.clusters[i].processes.length + ",";
        }

        console.log(clength);
    }

    var inspector = setInterval(inspect, 1000);
};
//much later
timer_func();
```

I am 100% I initialize what here is called `this.clusters` in my code before calling `timer_func()` but still apparently the variable that I try to access is undefined (whereas if I print it somewhere else outside the timeout is not). Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Do you see `timer_func` having any `clusters` property?

Comment: What is the parameter `clusters` in your `inspect()` function for? When you actually call `inspect()` via `setInterval()` no parameter will be passed in, but in any case you don't actually use that parameter anywhere in the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the problem is in how you call `timer_func()`, not in the use of `setInterval()`. If you want `this` *inside* `timer_func()` to refer to the same object you were setting properties for via the `this` *outside* `timer_func()` then call it as follows:

```
timer_func.call(this);
```

Comment: I was so focused on the setInterval that I didn't think about this. Thanks a lot, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The property `clusters` is never defined on the object, nor is the parameter `clusters` passed to the inner function.  You can go in one of two directions, specify the property or pass the parameters.

### Specify the property

```
var timer_func = function(){
    this.clusters = ["cluster1", "cluster2"];
    var that = this;
    var inspect = function(clusters){

        var clength = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < that.clusters.length; i++){   //---> undefined that.clusters.length
            clength += that.clusters[i].processes.length + ",";
        }

        console.log(clength);
    }

    var inspector = setInterval(inspect, 1000);
};
//much later
timer_func();
```

### Pass the Parameter

```
var timer_func = function(){
    var that = this;
    var inspect = function(clusters){

        var clength = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < clusters.length; i++){
            clength += clusters[i].processes.length + ",";
        }

        console.log(clength);
    }

    var inspector = setInterval(function(){
       var clusters = ["cluster1", "cluster2"]; 
       inspect(clusters)
    }, 1000);
};
//much later
timer_func();
```

---

Comment: I completely confused the scope of the `timer_func` with the scope of the object containing my `timer_func` function. Thanks for the in-depth answer.

Comment: @Masiar Glad I could help.  So I'm guessing the second approach is what you needed?

Comment: Yep. But your answer helped me understand why.